# jQuery - Get Alt text and add to alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jQuery and Javascript so I apologise if this is a silly question.  Wasn't quite sure what I needed to search for.

What I'm trying to do is find an empty href, and onclick return an alert with "Missing Link For + Alt Text"

I've tried a few things, all results weren't as I needed though.  The closest I've got was ALL alt text being returned one after the other after one click on an empty href.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
    var altText = $(this).find('#main a').attr('alt');

    $('#main a[href=""]').click(function(x){
        alert("Missing Link For " + altText);
        x.preventDefault();
     });
```

I've also fiddled it here: http://jsfiddle.net/M3tEg/

Any help would be great!  I feel like I'm close, but just missing something silly!  (That could not be the case, I'm hardly even a novice at the moment!!)

Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `find()` as you're already clicking on `a` itself! and also initialize your variable `altText` inside the `click()` so that you can get the attribute of the current/clicked one.

Just do this

```
altText = $(this).attr('alt');
```

---

```
    var altText;
    $('#main a[href=""]').click(function(x){
        altText = $(this).attr('alt');
        alert("Missing Link For " + altText);
        x.preventDefault();
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3tEg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead !

```
$('#main a[href=""]').click(function(x){
    alert("Missing Link For " + $(this).attr('alt'));
    x.preventDefault();
});
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3tEg/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Pay your attention on allowed attributes. There's no "alt" attribute for anchor (<a>). Only "title".
And you can get title as a property of you anchor. Like this:

```
$('#main a[href=""]').click(function(x){
    alert("Missing Link For " + this.title);
    x.preventDefault();
 });
```

But if you still want to use alt for anchor, replace "this.title" with "this.getAttribute('alt')".
Oh, and try to use less jQuery and more native js

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main a[href=""]').click(function(x){
    alert("Missing Link For " + $(this).attr('alt'));
    x.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
this.getAttribute('alt')
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ueyg2/)